# Is this conditional expectation decreasing?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Given some (integrable) function $f(x,y)$ with $\partial f/\partial x \leq 0$ and $\partial f/\partial y \leq 0$, and given two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with $\text{cov}(X,Y) \geq 0$, is it true that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left( f(x,Y) \mid X = x \right)
$$
is weakly decreasing in $x$?

Intuitively, it looks as though it should be but I can't see how to prove it. If it's not, it seems that there should be some minor modification that would make some similar statement true - that would also be very helpful to know.

Comment: i think you mean $E(f(X,Y)|X=x)$.

Comment: @Lost1 Aren't they the same thing?

Comment: actually yeah... sorry. with regard to your question. I am sceptical about the result. I may be mistaken, but the gut feeling is that covariance is not enough unless you know more about the distribution (e.g. it is Gaussian). I am almost certainly convinced that one can construct a discrete counter example, a continuous one needs more fiddling

Comment: @Lost1 Hmm... you may be right about that. If so, and if there is a natural strengthening of the $\text{cov}(X,Y) \geq 0$ assumption that would make the conclusion true, that would count as a good answer to the question!

Comment: making $(X,Y)$ jointly normal with positive correlation is the only thing *I think* that would work. I need to go to a lecture now. will check back on this when i get back